# No me lleva a la página de error 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error404, react-router-dom

Estoy cargando la ruta de Error 404 con `react-router-dom`, pero no funciona, sino que me redirige a la página principal. No entiendo por qué

```javascript
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import "./App.css";
    import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
    import SimpleBottomNavigation from "./components/MainNav";
    import Trending from "./Pages/Trending/Trending";
    import Movies from "./Pages/Movies/Movies";
    import Series from "./Pages/Series/Series";
    import Search from "./Pages/Search/Search";
    import MyList from "./Pages/MyList/MyList";
    import Error404 from "./Pages/Error404/Error404";
    import { langContext } from "./context/langContext";

    function App() {
      const idioma = useContext(langContext);
      console.log({ idioma });

      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header></Header>
          <div className="App">
            <Container>
              <Switch>
                <Route component={Trending} exact path="/"></Route>
                <Route component={Movies} exact path="/movies"></Route>
                <Route component={Series} exact path="/series"></Route>
                <Route component={Search} exact path="/search"></Route>
                <Route component={MyList} exact path="/mylist"></Route>
                <Route component={Error404} path="*"></Route>
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </div>
          <SimpleBottomNavigation></SimpleBottomNavigation>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Hasta donde tengo entendido, se añade un "*" a la ruta, pero al intentar escribir una url diferente a las ya mapeadas, me devuleve a la página principal.

Comment: Cómo estas navegando a la ruta? Y a qué ruta estas navegando? Tambien agrega el componente home y el de error404

Comment: Para tratar de llegar a esa ruta, escribo cualquier cosa luego del http://localhost:3000/ pero me devuelve al home, que en este caso es el componente Trending.

Comment: No es neceario path="*" en las última versiones de react-router-dom.

Comment: Puedes agregar los componentes Home y Error404?

Comment: En la documentacion dice exactamente lo que tu has hecho (https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) asi que seguramente el problema está en otro lado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola amigo a mi me paso lo mismo y lo solucione cambiando:

- `BrowserRouter` por `HashRouter`
- Cambia
  `<Route component={Error404} path="*"></Route>`
  por
  `<Route component={Error404}/>`
- Y cambia las otras rutas  por ejemplo:
  `<Route component={MyList} exact path="/mylist"></Route>`
  por
  `<Route path={'/mylist'} component = {mylist}></Route>`

Comment: muchas gracias! funcionó!